# i have problem in flutter code. Its giving be RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox object was given an infinite size during layout

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am new to flutter and am trying to implement custom list view in flutter. Its giving be RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox object was given an infinite size during layout error

I am not able to get for which widget its throwing error
2 Also please suggest how to debug these layout errors as the error trace doesn't have specific widget info for which error is thrown

please find the below code for the same:

```
_list.length <= 0
        ? Center(
            child: Text('Add from bottom button',
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                    color: Colors.blue)))
        : Column(
            children: [Container(
              height: 200,
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemBuilder: (context, index) => _list[index],
                itemCount: _list.length,
              ),
            ),
         ] ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrapped the list view inside the `Column` and `Container` widget. Column has infinite width and height. You should provide `width` to the container and also enable shrinkWrap to true in ListView. Find the code snippets below:

```
_list.length <= 0
        ? Center(
            child: Text('Add from bottom button',
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                    color: Colors.blue)))
        : Column(
            children: [Container(
              width: 360, 
              height: 200,
              child: ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) => _list[index],
                itemCount: _list.length,
              ),
            ),
         ] ),
```