# RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox object was given an infinite size during layout inside PageRouteBuilder

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I already went through few posts (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53737363/rendercustommultichildlayoutbox-object-was-given-an-infinite-size-during-layout), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66847630/i-have-problem-in-flutter-code-its-giving-be-rendercustommultichildlayoutbox-ob), etc) mentioning the same error but their solutions didn't work.

**Minimal reproducible code:**

```dart
class MyPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () => Navigator.push(context, MyRoute(child: Page2())),
        child: Text('Navigate'),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyRoute extends PageRouteBuilder {
  final Widget child;
  MyRoute({this.child}) : super(pageBuilder: (_, __, ___) => child);

  @override
  Widget buildTransitions(_, __, ___, ____) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        Positioned(
          left: 0,
          child: child, // Doesn't work
          // child: FlutterLogo(size: 100), // Works
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class Page2 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Page 2')));
}
```

The problem is happening in the `buildTransitions()` method when I return `child` in `Positioned`. However, returning other widgets like a `FlutterLogo` does seem to work.

> The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
> RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox object was given an infinite size during layout.

I tried wrapping my `Stack` in a `SizedBox` but that didn't work.

Note: I know I can simply return `child` and do other such things like setting `right`, `top` and `bottom` property to `0` in `Positioned`, but my question isn't about solving it, but rather why there's an error, what's causing the infinite size?

**Edit (added stack trace)**

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: 'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart': Failed assertion: line 2773 pos 18: 'transformed == position - childParentData.offset': is not true.
#0      _AssertionError._doThrowNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:46:39)
#1      _AssertionError._throwNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:36:5)
#2      RenderBoxContainerDefaultsMixin.defaultHitTestChildren.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2773:18)
#3      BoxHitTestResult.addWithPaintOffset (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:786:31)
#4      RenderBoxContainerDefaultsMixin.defaultHitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2769:33)
#5      RenderStack.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/stack.dart:620:12)
#6      RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2413:11)
#7      RenderProxyBoxMixin.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:131:19) <37 more lines>
```

Comment: post first 8-10 frames of the stacktrace

Comment: @pskink Edited the post. Please check out.

Comment: @pskink Updated the post, are you not able to reproduce the issue?

Comment: *"but rather why there's an error, what's causing the infinite size?"* - seems that you should read [Understanding constraints](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout/constraints) article and run all 29 provided examples